# Compare two columns of words

Tags: excel, excel-formula, string-comparison, worksheet-function, countif

I have two columns in Excel:

```
**A1:A300**            **C1:C300**         

    ABBEY               3i Group PLC
    ABN AMRO            3M Co.  
    ACCOR               A2A SpA 
    ACKERMANS           AREAL BANK  
    ...                 ABB     
                        Abbey National  
                        ...
```

Is it possible to compare these for repeated words?

Comment: You could try VLOOKUP.  But I think you still need to give it a string to match first.  I don't think you can compare two columns and have it list where certain string match without specifying WHAT to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 =COUNTIF(C$1:C$300,A1)
```

in Row 1 and copied down to suit.

The result should be the number of times the A column value for the corresponding row features in Column C.

`ABBEY` would not 'match' with `ABBEY NATIONAL`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a COUNTIF formula

In column B (or wherever you want it)

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C$300,"="&A1)
```

Filled down for each cell in column A. This will tell you if there's anything in column A that is in column C

With this formula, and data I have this output:

```
Column A      Column C       Column D    Column E
ABBEY         ABBEY          2           2
ABBEY ROAD    ABBEY ROAD     1           1
ABBEYS        ABBEY          0           0
```

Where Column D is

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C$300,"="&A1)
```

And Column E is

```
=COUNTIF(C$1:C$300, A1)
```

Both are valid formulas

Comment: =COUNTIF(C1:C300,"="&A1)
Don't work, is that correct using "="?

Comment: I've edited my answer, the formula I provided definitely works.